# What did Maz Kanata give to Chewie?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

What did Maz Kanata give to Chewie in the end of the Episode IX? Have we seen this (golden?) object before? What makes it significant?

Comment: The medal that he was long denied. Also, dupe question supposedly.

Answer (score 8):

It’s one of the medals that Leia gives out at the end of *A New Hope* to Han and Luke. I’d imagine it’s Han’s and that’s why it was meaningful.

[image: Luke and Han with their medals at the ceremony]

Comment: The medal that Chewie should have got in the first place!

Answer (score 7):

As TheLethalCarrot said, it's one of the Alliance medals given to Luke and Han in *A New Hope*.

My interpretation of its significance had been that it's a response to Chewie not getting a medal after the Battle of Yavin, which some fans have seen as unfair (since he didn't do any less than Han), and which has had [varying explanations and retcons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/why-didnt-chewbacca-get-a-medal-after-the-battle-of-yavin) over the years.

It's not clear whether Chewie getting the medal is an in-universe acknowledgement of his bravery during the Battle of Exegol, or if it really was just Han's and Maz Kanata had it lying around. He apparently *did* get a medal after Yavin according to [Disney canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/135683/21154), so it would have to be either a retcon or a second medal, but he waves it around triumphantly after receiving it, so it would be odd if that was his reaction to receiving something of Han's. A third possibility is that it's just another medal of the same type, and has no deeper significance in-universe.