# Did Chewie reference the old "Han shot first" debate in "The Force Awakens"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I was wondering if they referenced the Han Shot First Debate In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, due to this line:

> Rey: What are you gonna do?
>
> Han Solo: Same thing I always do. Talk my way out of it.
>
> [Chewie growls a comment]
>
> Han Solo: Yes, I do. Every time.

Presumably, that growl was "no you don't" or "not always", thus referencing the infamous [Han shot first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/why-is-it-called-han-shot-first) argument.

Comment: I was the only one to laugh in the cinema when it happened, you see...

Comment: I always thought it was a ridiculous argument. If I were Han, I would have shot first too.

Comment: Chewie's growl could also be interpreted as a comment on how *successfully* Han manages to talk his way out of things, as opposed to whether or not he always makes the attempt. Since ultimately this is a question about the out-of-universe intentions of the writer(s) behind the scene, it'll be tricky to answer definitively unless they've already written or talked about this, or somebody manages to ask them at some point in the future.

Comment: *the **old** “Han shot first” debate* – Now I feel old.

Comment: @MikasaPinata You're not alone.  I love this scene too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Nah, the problem is, EVERY single time Han tries to talk his way out of problems..... it backfires.

- Greedo (Ep 4)
- Detention Center (Ep 4)
- Lando (Ep 5) - got betrayed
- Vader (Ep 5) ....got frozen
- Jabba (Eps 4 and 6, especially Ep 6)

And after that conversation with Chewie:

- The Rathar incident (Ep 7)
- His son (Ep 7)

And Chewie? He was there for EVERY single instance. So one doesn't wonder much that he is laughing/finds it quite ironic at Han being able to talk his way out of things.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't necessarily refer to that: in Episode V at the Cloud City dinner scene he shoots at Vader right away instead of asking "What is he doing here?"

Comment: At least we can all agree that in that instance, Han shot first