# Who was "The Chosen One": Luke or Anakin?

Tags: star-wars

Most would say that Luke is because he is the focus of the first movies (4-6), but Qui-gon said Anakin was "The Chosen One".

Who was the real "Chosen One"?

Comment: Also check http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force/

Comment: I think that episodes 4-6 still focus on developing Darth Vader as a person.  Each part he becomes a little more human, until in the end he takes off his mask and dies as a good man.

Comment: He is confirmed to be the Chosen One in the canon Star Wars: The Clone Wars show. (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_to_Mortis/Canon)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's Anakin.

Luke was a very powerful Jedi, that's why he was "a new hope" for Ben and Yoda.  He had the Force potential to become what his father was supposed to become, the Force potential of the Chosen One ([ref](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker#Force_powers)).

Meanwhile, It's Anakin who fulfilled the [Prophecy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One) by ([temporarily](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine#Palpatine_reborn_.284.E2.80.9311_ABY.29)) killing the [Emperor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) and brought balance to the Force.

Finally :

> **George Lucas himself** has stated that Anakin is the Chosen One and that the prophecy is true, although Luke indirectly served as the catalyst that allowed Anakin to fulfill the prophecy.
>   - [Star Wars wiki, "Chosen One" article, "Behind the scenes" section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One#Behind_the_scenes)

Comment: You may want to see the 3-episode arc that started with [this episode](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Overlords) of *The Clone Wars*.  It expands on the 'Chosen One' mythos.

Comment: @DavRob60: what do you mean, "*temporarily* killed the Emperor"?

Comment: @Wikis: He got better.  It was called 'Dark Forces' and it was primarily represented in the Dark Horse comics.

Comment: @Wikis I added a link on that `temporarily` braced allusion.

Comment: @Jeff 'He got better' Monty Python reference? :)

Comment: @john: Of course.  I never miss a chance to use a good python reference.

Comment: Anakin was also the one who was actually born of the force and resulting from immaculate conception (like Jesus and Neo).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté It's a little off-topic, but [immaculate conception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception) is not [virgin birth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_birth). Go revise your Catechism. Also chek [who is Anakin Skywalkers father](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/who-is-anakin-skywalkers-father)

Comment: @Jeff I think you mean Dark Empire series I and II and there was also a closing series of 2 books called Dark Empire: Empire's End.  Excellent series at the time, but I wonder if newer fans of all Clone Wars series and spin-offs might find them a bit ho-hum.

Comment: I also recall that Force prophecies are vague at best. I cannot recall from where, but I read that there was one such prophecy where someone was supposed to be the hero of a great battle, and the prophecy was "fulfilled" because this hero was somehow ejected out of his starship, died, and the now floating starship crashed into an enemy fleet. Had he not been ejected out of his starship, he would have avoided the fleet, thus NOT causing it's destruction.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté ok I have to ask.  What do you mean Neo?  Does Matrix really say he had no dad?

Answer (score 38):

I always favored a more literal interpretation of the "bring balance to the Force" part of the Chosen One prophecy.  At the beginning of the prequel trilogy there are many Jedi but only two Sith.  During Episode III and in the gap between III and IV, Darth Vader kills most of the Jedi, so that at the beginning of Episode IV only Obi-Wan Kenobi and Yoda remain.  So by this point in the series, balance has been brought to the Force and the prophecy has been fulfilled... from a certain point of view.

Comment: Since George Lucas himself stated that "bring balance to the Force" mead "destroying the Sith", I don't see why any others interpretation could be valid.

Comment: @DavRob60: Because 1) there were many different revisions to the script before the final version was filmed, and 2) the Emperor was only temporarily dead, so the canonical interpretation doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: but 1) this was stated After the final version was filmed (on the DVD commentary of Revenge of the Sith) 2) The Emperor's rebirth was also contested. I did not read many Star Wars book, so I'm pretty sure it was in [Vision of the Future](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vision_of_the_Future) that there was doubts about the nature of the reborn emperor. Anyway, if "canonical interpretation doesn't make much sense" It's still the canonical interpretation. And it wouldn't be the [first time the fans don't agree](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2286)

Comment: @DavRob60: I agree that as the canonical interpretation there's not much point in debating it.  If Lucas says that killing the Emperor fulfilled the prophecy, then that's what happened.  But Han shot first.  ;)

Comment: I guess it really depends on if you view 'Jedi vs Sith' as 'good vs evil' (or 'order vs chaos'), or as 'balance vs whatever's the opposite of balance'

Comment: @Random832 - Imbalance?

Comment: So your interpretation of "balance" is of each side having the same number of members? That seems like a very superficial balance that has little bearing on the state of the galaxy. There may have been 2 main players on each team at the start of the original trilogy, but the balance of power was certainly biased towards the dark side. The empire was essentially controlled by the dark side, which ruled most of the galaxy. Whereas Obi-Wan and Yoda provided pretty much no light side force to counter this dark side influence. That's not balance IMO.

Comment: "All that is necessary for evil to triumph is for good men to do nothing." I always viewed the Jedi as holding the galaxy back from slipping into the abyss, so to speak.  Palpatine pushed it past the tipping point and Anakin was needed to restore balance.  Of course you can argue people are naturally "good" ... but I don't believe it :P

Comment: @MatthewRead - +100 for this. I wish I could upvote again

Answer (score 17):

Anakin was the chosen one. He was supposed to destroy the Sith and later on become the most powerful Jedi ever. Palpatine got to him too early before he knew what was good for him. Everyone was testing him at once, the council, obi-wan and the force (his dreams). The only reassurance he got was from Palpatine.

While training Luke, Yoda explained that Anakin was powerful, but he could never focus on the "right now", and that he was always looking to the future. He never realized at the moment of action what he was actually doing because he was so impatient of what was supposed to come to him it led him down a bad path.

Balance can be interpreted in many ways, however the point is he is the chosen one. Maybe he was always fated to fall and kill the Sith from within as a Sith. It's confusing. It could also mean balance can only be brought by the chosen one and that balance would be brought through the chosen one's vision of what balance is. Maybe Anakin got to decide the whole time what balance was. Palpatine just suckered him in to ruling it to his own favor.

Anakin survived being mutilated and burned alive by lava, but that should just prove he is the chosen one. He was powerful enough to stay alive, but why?

In his lifetime, he was supposed to bring this prophetic balance into place. Whats to say after balance was brought he wouldn't die? After all, isn't that his purpose? It would explain why he died at the end of ROTJ, instead of simply blaming it on the electricity.

Maybe the republican Jedi were unbalancing the force as well by their lifestyle. No attachments, no love, nothing. Breeding an army of laser-deflecting emotionless unattached warriors probably did not serve in the will of the force's favor. Think about it, Anakin fell to the dark side for love (Padmé), but fell back to the light side for love (Luke). Maybe the power of love is greater than the power of the force. The force should not take priority over a lifestyle but accompany the lifestyle in a great way.

In the prequels, the Jedi prided themselves too much on their ability to be fierce warriors and to deflect bullets from droids. The war Palpatine created exploited the Jedi's weakness.

Obi-Wan and Yoda only became true Jedi masters in the OT. Qui Gon Jinn had to redirect them and train them back into the proper ways. They stopped relying so much on their lightsabers and more on their wit, their meditation and being in-tune with the force.

"A Jedi uses the force for knowledge and defence, never for attack" however we see the Jedi being launched into war, hunting droids and several separatist organizations. They go against their own code all throughout the prequels. Only in OT are they truly peaceful Jedi, wise and in tune with the force.

Being raised and trained during the war Anakin quickly became a skilled warrior and very powerful, but it drove him to be quick to draw his blade and start a fight. He was never properly taught to be a Jedi. Palpatine knew this would happen. Instead of the council focusing on training Anakin to be the ultimate chosen one, they chose to focus on the war he created. This distracted the council from training Anakin properly and made all the Jedi very on edge all the time. "Our ability to use the force has diminished" – Windu even said it himself that they failed as Jedi.

At the end of ROTS, when Yoda sends Obi Wan to fight Anakin, then goes to fight Palpatine, that's why he exiled himself. It was this decision, a decision of pure arrogance ("Your arrogance blinds you master Yoda" Sidious to Yoda) and only at the end of that duel did he realize he made a huge mistake. Only the Chosen One could kill the Sith, so why not go with Obi Wan to see Anakin instead of making Obi Wan fight the Chosen One who had been wrongly deemed a true Sith. They only saw a few clips of what Anakin did but they never saw the whole story. They were too quick to draw conclusions and they were acting sporadically and quickly without much thought.

They should have both gone to see Anakin first, calmed him down together and them the three of them take on Palpatine, but no Yoda thought he could take on Palpatine. ("His abilities have made him, well, arrogant"-Obi wan "A trait more and more common among Jedi, even the older, more experienced ones." Yoda). Little did he know...

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: What does OT stand for?

Comment: @Tyrsius Original Trilogy.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Never thought about Yoda's arrogance making him vulnerable in RoS.

Answer (score 8):

In the Star Wars Rebels episode "Twin Suns", Maul

> finds Obi-Wan on Tatooine and fights him

He figures out that Obi-Wan is "protecting someone" (who we know is Luke).

> MAUL: Look what has become of you. A rat in the desert. Look what I have risen above. I've come to kill you, but perhaps it's worse to leave you here, festering in your squalor.
>
>  OBI-WAN: If you define yourself by your power to take life, a desire to dominate, to possess, then you have nothing.
>
>  MAUL: And what do you have? Why come to this place? Not simply to hide. Oh, you have a purpose here. Perhaps you are protecting something... **No, protecting someone**.

After Obi-Wan

> defeats Maul, and before he dies,

Maul asks Obi-Wan: "Tell me. Is it the Chosen One?", to which Obi-Wan replies: "He is".

After a cut scene, we see Obi-Wan

> riding to the outskirt of Uncle Owen's farm, where he hears Aunt Beru calling Luke inside, in a similar fashion to how she does in Star Wars Episode IV.

**So, in Disney TV canon, it appears Luke is now set as the Chosen One!** Anakin may or may not have been the Chosen One during the prequel trilogy, but he does not appear to be so going into the original trilogy.

Comment: It's no guarantee that Obi-Wan is referring to Luke. He could be protecting Anakin ultimately by protecting Luke who may redeem him.

Comment: Perhaps. I forgot Maul's final words after: "He will avenge us". Now, he could be thinking that the Chosen One will avenge him, which would not make sense if it is Luke. Or he could just be thinking of someone else in his final thoughts. Anakin maybe? But Anakin didn't like Maul, so why would he care that Obi-Wan defeated Maul? However, in a followup scene, Obi-Wan goes to Owen's farm, presumably to make sure Luke is OK. So that is still a good indication to me that Obi-Wan was referring to Luke when asked if he was protecting the Chosen One.

Comment: In EIII, Kenobi laments to Anakin that he, Anakin, was supposed to have been the Chosen One. Clearly that turned out to not be the case (to Kenobi, from a certain point of view) since Anakin fell to the Dark Side. In Kenobi's mind then, clearly Luke is to be the Chosen One. The events of RoTJ may still lead one to believe that Anakin ultimately did fulfill the original prophecy of him being the Chosen One. Also - Kenobi is speaking....he's probably lying ;)

Comment: I believe that this is a very wrong answer

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer and I suspect that will become clear in **The Last Jedi**. It was largely speculated in the Prequels and in the Clone Wars series that Anakin was the chosen one, but no one ever states that he is with as much conviction as Obi Wan does to Maul in reference to Luke. Even that weird episode on the Force planet, the Father only *believes* Anakin to be the chosen one, and that is just because of Anakin's power.

Comment: It appears I was wrong. This was not made clear in The Last Jedi, and, considering the ending, it doesn't look like anyone in universe actually knows who the chosen one is. Maybe it will be Rey or Ben, but Obi Wan certainly didn't think it was Anakin in the end.

Comment: Season 6 of Clone Wars makes it pretty clear that Luke is at least *a* Chosen One, because Qui Gon explicitly says he is guiding Yoda into how to become a force ghost because it is part of the path to a Chosen One that will correct a great imbalance; dialogue strongly implies it's Luke specifically. That Anakin was also one, only a failed one, is questionable. Much of the Clone Wars series supports the notion that Anakin was pretty much destined to become Vader pretty early on; especially the Mortis saga. Filoni's comments suggest that his fall was guaranteed as soon as Qui Gon was felled.

Answer (score 2):

> "Anakin is the chosen one"
>
> <sub><sup>[Featurette: The Chosen One - George Lucas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqLsQClut5c&feature=youtu.be&t=1m46s)</sup></sub>

Anakin is clearly the chosen one. Now the problem with the fans they're thinking Luke because anakin turns to the dark side.Because without Luke in the first place,Anakin will not fulfill his mission. Supposedly by now, they should now think  that Anakin is the chosen One. Because He is just Like Jesus Christ. After he died he appeared again.

Now, Let me view my point of view as Catholic Liturgical Calendar like Easter,Christmas, Ordinary Time and Lent. In  The Return of The Jedi is the episode where the redemption of anakin occurs. The Redemption of Anakin is the Easter season of Star Wars. In the Revenge of the Sith until empire Strikes Back , It is the Lenten Season.

Fans of the Original Trilogy,Were thinking that Luke Skywalker is the Chosen One. My Brothers and Sisters Luke Skywalker is not the chosen one. He is just the catalyst of the chosen one. Meaning he is the one who cause Anakin to fulfill his prophecy as the chosen One.The Main Antagonst in Star wars is Palpatine. Who is the satanic figure in the saga. In ROTJ,Anakin was awakened and Darth Vader was destroyed. It is anakin who throws palpatine not vader.

Please watch this video,For more details

Answer (score 1):

The chosen one was Anakin but probably the Jedi didn`t read the prophecy in the right way.

> The chosen one must bring balance in the Force.

When Palpatine had said that Jedi had become arrogant, dominant, too aggressive in *Revenge of The Sith*, it was true so the balance of the Force, in this case, pending to the Dark side. Why?

Obi-Wan betrayed Anakin. He left him to die on Mustafar. That wasn`t a Jedi behaviour. Mace Windu was going to kill Palpatine until Anakin said that Jedi did not do such things. Jedi fought. Jedi killed. Jedi betrayed. On the other way Sith become a friend. Sith understood.

Another explanation:
When Darth Plagueis played with Force, altering the number of Midichlorians, the Force itself created something in response of this offense - created Anakin. Anakin was supposed to be the Force itself. The Force brought Qui-Gon to Anakin - the Sith violated the nature of being - for to meet him. Only this. But Qui-Gon also played with Force to take Anakin out of his natural homeland. So The Force in this point left to Anakin the decision of what in right. And Anakin killed all old Jedi council because the Force.

But then his son, although Vader had killed and tortured so many people, loved him and made Vader sacrifice his life for something bigger than himself. And then the Prophecy become a reality. Anakin is suppose to be the Chosen one but Luke, a  son of the Force, is his guidance and his words.

So I would say that **both Anakin and Luke was the Chosen one altogether**. *Without Luke`s actions, love, loyalty, innocence Anakin would have never killed the Emperor and fulfilled his destiny.*

Answer (score 0):

**Anakin is the Chosen One.** In *[Overlords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Overlords)*, an episode of *The Clone Wars*, the [Force wielders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_wielder/Canon) subject him to a test to see if he is, which he passes. Excerpt from Wookieepedia:

> After Anakin Skywalker successfully passed a test by subduing both the
>   Son and the Daughter, the Father recognized him as the Chosen One who
>   was destined to take his place as warden of the children.

Comment: Disagree. They, like everyone else, only *believe* him to be the chosen one because of his power. No one is ever *sure* who the chosen one is until Obi Wan states that is is Luke in Star Wars Rebels.