# How was the Chosen One meant to bring balance to the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The legend of the Chosen One foretold the coming of a being who would restore balance to the Force.

Now we know that Anakin Skywalker was the Chosen One, but how exactly was he supposed to restore balance?

Is a balance to the Force:

- eliminating all Dark Side users so that only the Light Side remains?
- reducing the Dark Side's influence to almost nothing, but still leaving some Dark Side users so that there is a balance of energies? (End of Episode VI, there are still Dark Side users in Legends)
- creating an equal presence on both sides?
  (for example, at the end of Episode III it appears that there are two Sith [Sidious and Vader] and two Jedi [Yoda and Obi-Wan])
- Any other way not mentioned above?

And whichever the legend means, has the prophecy been completed? Has the Chosen One restored balance to the Force at one point, or did he fail to fulfill the prophecy?

So in short,
**What is the meaning of 'balance' when it is said that "The Chosen One will bring balance to the Force", and did he fulfill the prophecy?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did the Jedi want to bring balance to the Force?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question asks why the Jedi wanted to bring balance and what they *thought* the prophecy meant. This question is asking what the *original prophecy* meant and *how it was ultimately fulfilled in reality*

Comment: then it's a duplicate of : [Was Luke or Anakin “The Chosen One”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/was-luke-or-anakin-the-chosen-one)

Comment: I don't think that one is either. That one just asks "Who was the Chosen One" - still different than "What did the Chosen One do", which is really what this question is about

Comment: But it still answer the question.

Comment: Your assumptions are somewhat flawed.  There were more than two Jedi left at the end of Ep III.  We are only shown two.  There were others scattered across the galaxy going into hiding.  Most of them were eventually hunted down by Vader, but even in the days of Luke and the Rebel Alliance, there were never just two remaining.

Comment: @DavRob60 while related this is a different question.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> eliminating all Dark Side users so that only the Light Side remains?

No.

> reducing the Dark Side's influence to almost nothing, but still leaving some Dark Side users so that there is a balance of energies? (End of Ep VI, there are still Dark Side users in EU)

No.

> creating an equal presence on both sides?
>   (for example, at the end of Ep III there are two Sith [Sidious and Vader] and two Jedi [Yoda and Obi-Wan])

No.

> Any other way not mentioned above?

Yes. :)

In the commentary of A New Hope, G. Lucas said:

> Which brings us up to the films 4, 5, and 6, in which Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe...

Which proves that balance does not mean equal number of Sith and Jedi.

The meaning of the prophecy is not totally clear, as noted by Yoda. But we still have some infos about it, for instance in [Darth Plagueis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis):

> Brazen and shameless, and at their own mortal peril, they had waged etheric war, anticipating that their own midi-chlorians, the Force’s proxy army, might marshal to boil their blood or stop the beating of their hearts. Risen out of themselves, discorporate and as a single entity, they had brought the power of their will to bear, **asserting their sovereignty over the Force**.

This shows the difference between a dark sider and a Sith Lord. A dark sider is a force sensitive individual using the dark side of the Force. A Sith Lord tries to put the Force itself,in all its aspects, to its service.

That's why the Force tried to destroy the Sith, as they are at war with the Force itself.

There were also some infos in the [Clone Wars animated series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(TV_series)) during three episodes: Overlords, Altar of Mortis, Ghosts of Mortis. In those episodes, it is shown that the Light side and the Dark side are equally important part of the Force, both being necessary to the harmony of the galaxy.

In one episode Anakin must pass a test to show if he's the Chosen One: he does so by controlling both sides of the Force at the same time.

[image: The two sides of the Force kneeling before the Chosen One]

So it seems that in the Star Wars universe the dark side is not evil by nature (a position held by Vergere for instance), and that it's closer to a ying/yang situation, where harmony comes from balance between the two sides.

So the prophecy probably means that Anakin would bring harmony between the two sides of the Force, which requires the destruction of the Sith whose aim was to destroy the Light side.

It's interesting to see such an interpretation of the prophecy does not really corresponds to Jedi orthodoxy, especially during the post-Ruusan reformation, where the Jedi decided to cut themselves utterly from the Dark side by renouncing to any and all emotions.

Version of the Jedi code during Anakin's era:

```
There is no emotion, there is peace.
There is no ignorance, there is knowledge.
There is no passion, there is serenity.
(There is no chaos, there is harmony.)(*)
There is no death, there is the Force.
```

Original version:

```
Emotion, yet peace.
Ignorance, yet knowledge.
Passion, yet serenity.
Chaos, yet harmony.
Death, yet the Force.
```

There is a huge difference during the two: one seeks balance, the other deny the very existence of the Dark side.

I would also note that as the Dark side leads to death (Korriban becoming a desert planet), this new version of the Order became sterile due to its rules against attachments. Looking at Anakin, who was the Force made flesh, it seems that the dark side (and so emotions) is as legitimate than the Light side as a part of the Force, and that balance means equilibrium between the sides, and not annihilation of one.

> and did he fulfill the prophecy?

Good question.

In G and T level canon yes, Lucas said it himself.

In C canon a good case can be made that he didn't, as the Sith came back.

Comment: Great answer--just to add some relevant info, there are some good quotes from George Lucas on the need for balance between the two sides of the force posted [here](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=660752&page=3#27). He does associate the dark side with "evil" but says "they both need to be there". Also see [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22772/22250) suggesting the Sith were unbalancing the force itself by strengthening the dark side and diminishing the light side everywhere.

Answer (score 29):

This is answered in the recent book [*Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis).

> When Darth Plagueis used his abilities in manipulating midi-cholrians, the midi-chlorians rebelled and caused the conception of Anakin Skywalker. His birth was an effort by the midi-chlorians to *balance* the works of the Sith.

Ultimately, he brought balance to the force by ending the millenia-long conflict between Sith and Jedi, albeit temporarily ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_One#History_of_the_Chosen_One)):

> It transpired, however, that the prophecy was still to be momentarily fulfilled; decades later, above the moon of Endor. There, Vader stood witness to a confrontation between the Dark Lord of the Sith, Palpatine, and Vader's own son, Luke Skywalker. When Palpatine unleashed violent Force lightning upon the boy, Anakin Skywalker returned and turned against his Sith Master in a violent attempt to save Luke's life. It was this conscious choice that fulfilled the Prophecy and brought a temporary balance to the Force. Skywalker killed Sidious at the cost of his own life, and in doing so, fulfilled the prophecy by destroying the Sith leadership, his Master's original body and himself.

Thus, the balance was not so much an equal measure of dark and light, but a *restoring* force, and as such, Anakin Skywalker did ultimately fulfill the prophecy.

Comment: In this respect, Anakin was able to do something that no other jedi (turned into Sith) could do. Yoda said "If once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny.". On the other end Anakin was able to correct his mistake and redeem himself.

Answer (score 9):

He was meant to take the place of the Father and balance the son and the daughter of the Celestials.  When he turned his back on that obligation he set in motion events that would threaten the galaxy.  The story takes place over a 3 episode arc of [The Clone Wars TV series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458290/).  The arc starts [Season 3 Episode 15](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1707615/) and ends in Episode 17 These events come to head in the current EU series *Fate of the Jedi*.

Comment: Can you please supply links or a greater explanation? I have not yet read the _Fate of the Jedi_ series, and don't understand the references to 'Father', 'son' and 'daughter'. Sounds interesting though :)

Comment: @hammythepig - sadly the Celestials story played out in the Clone Wars Cartoon.  I added links to IMDB for the arc.

Comment: Good point. IIRC, had he taken the place of the Father, he would have brought balance to the force and avoided many things that later happened, including the rise of the empire. However, when he did not, that's when the alternate way to "bring balance" presented itself - killing Palpatine and "restoring" the previous balance

Answer (score 6):

Well, it is obvious from the events that if you are to believe the prophecy was true, then clearly the third option was correct. However, a far more interesting question is what did the Jedi THINK it meant. Obviously they didn't understand what it actually meant otherwise they wouldn't have supported it, or discussed it with such reverence.

My theory is that they saw themselves as the balance in the force, where the Dark side was the destabilization of the force. Chaos vs Order, Death vs Life, Impulsiveness vs Control. In that sense "balance to the force" would mean removing that which is unbalancing - or the defeat of the remaining sith.

Obviously this belief did not pan out well for them.

Comment: As far as what the Jedi thought it meant, go [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/why-did-the-jedi-want-to-bring-balance-to-the-force?lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

The ending of the new (canon) novelisation for Star Wars: Return of the Jedi specifically and explicitly states that the act that resulted in the return of "balance" to the Force was the death of The Emperor.

> *In the end, Anakin did what no Jedi—not Luke, not Obi-Wan, not even Yoda—could do.    **In killing his master**—the mighty Sith Lord Darth Sidious, known to the galaxy as Emperor Palpatine—**Anakin fulfilled his destiny and restored balance to the Force**. And so, though the   galaxy will not honor him…Luke will.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Beware the Power of the Dark Side!](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!)</sup></sub>

Comment: I wonder how Palpatine's return affects this? In Disney canon, does this make Rey the Chosen One since she is the one who ultimately destroys Palpatine (hopefully for the last time)?

Answer (score 5):

The balance of the Force is NOT a balance of the Force-users; Force-users are not the same thing as the Force. It is also not a balance of Force *use*. It is a cosmic balance between the light and dark sides of the Force themselves.

According to Lucas, the Force is balanced after ROTJ, at a point when there is 1 Jedi ( discounting Force ghosts ) and 0 Sith. The Force was *not* balanced at the end of ROTS. "You were supposed to destroy the Sith, not join them! Bring balance to the Force, **not leave it in darkness**." Furthermore, there were around 10,000 Jedi in TPM and only two Sith, while the Jedi clearly look forward to the fulfillment of the prophecy as a positive outcome ( they would not do so if it meant reducing their numbers to only two ). All of this evidence serves to contradict the popular misunderstanding that "balance of the Force" means "Jedi and Sith head count".

During the era of the films the Force is unbalanced toward the dark side. This is due to the activities of the latter-day Banite Sith who have caused the dark side to grow out of bounds in prominence. As Lucas said in the Los Angeles Times article "Flaws in a Good Heart": ***"As evil begins to take over, it pushes the Force out of balance."*** ( Whether this occurs precisely the way it did in *Darth Plagueis* is no longer clear due to the decanonization of "Legends" EU. ) Thus, the Force is brought into balance by destroying the Sith of the movie era, embodied by Palpatine, since the Sith were responsible for throwing the Force out of balance in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this reponse in a duplicate post.  I think it may be less canon, but I think it offers a better explanation then what is *somewhat* confirmed as the explanation:

I believe the prophecy of "the chosen one" was written much like a Greek Tragedy.  A great example would be the [Story of Oedipus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus).

At the time Anakin Skywalker was born, the Force was "unbalanced" heavily in favor of the Jedi, and it had been this way for a long time.  With the rise of the Sith, it was believed by the Jedi that the Force had become unbalanced, which has led to conflict.  By hearing of the prophecy of the one who will bring balance to the Force, the Jedi Council interpreted this as the one who will stop the Sith and bring peace as seen here:

> Obi-Wan Kenobi: With all due respect, Master, is he not the Chosen One? Is he not to destroy the Sith and bring balance to the Force?
>
> Mace Windu: So the prophecy says.
>
> Yoda: A prophecy that misread could have been.
>
> Obi-Wan Kenobi: He will not let me down. He never has.
>
> Yoda: I hope right you are.

It is clear here that Yoda is beginning to see that there is a possibility the prophecy was misread.

> Obi-Wan: You were the chosen one! It was said that you would destroy
>   the Sith, not join them. You were to bring balance to the force, not
>   leave it in darkness.

Now, during the life of Anakin Skywalker, we see the tragic downfall of a hero through a misinterpreted prophecy.  At birth, the Jedi Order greatly influences the Senate as seen in Episode I, II, III.  From the view of the Jedi (ode to Obi-Wan) the reappearance of the Sith has made things unbalanced.  This is **FALSE** since the Jedi vastly outnumber the Sith and hold great influence in the Senate and in turn, the galaxy.

The immediate actions of Palpatine **AFTER THE BALANCE WAS STRUCK** send the balance back in favor of the Sith.  The intent of the prophecy is not his actions at the Jedi Temple or through Order 66, but that moment in the Senate chambers.

So in conclusion, I believe at the moment Anakin chooses to save Palpatine, **he strikes balance to the Force for the first time in a thousand years**, by taking Mace Windu's arm, and for that brief moment the Sith and Jedi are in perfect balance, thus fulfilling his prophecy as "the one who will bring balance to the Force."

Answer (score 3):

The way I took it, and I could be way wrong...but I took it as he ended both the Jedi and the Sith in the long run. He killed off most the Jedi by betraying them and eventually the Sith would fall to his son. Even Luke wasn't a true Jedi(like Darth Vader) because he didn't dedicate his whole life to the Jedi way of the force.

Yoda even says it midway to late in the Return of the Sith (III):

> misread the prophecy may have been

which I added up to be is yes, Anakin was the chosen one, but just not the way they saw it or the way anyone could have. He brought balance to the force by ending both ways and making life normal with nobody being able to use the force. Which is probably best because that kind of power calls for unpredictable changes.

Don't get me wrong...I may be reading way to deep into this, but I can't help but think there was a deep message that may have been put into play with that quote, and in II they even said that Arrogance was a flaw that they were starting to see in more and more young Jedi. I may be wrong or way off, and if anybody already said exactly that sorry, but that is some food for thought. May the force be with all of you. -True Star Wars Nerd

Comment: Anakin didn't kill off most of the Jedi; that honor goes to clones of one J.Fett. Also, ROTJ in no way leaves us with a galaxy in which "nobody [is] able to use the Force".

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the force has always been unbalanced whether to the light or to the dark. Throughout the tens of thousands of years of backstory before Ep I is it possible there were other "chosen ones" picked by the force to equal the balance? Quite possible.

There have been some comments made previously but I'd like to go a step further. Both the Sith and Jedi were dissolussioned with what "balance" would bring. Though there are wide differences between the two sides of the force in appearance, knowledge, character, beliefs, etc. There is one underlying trait that both Sith and Jedi share that I feel the Force never intended for itself to be used as, Control. Prior to Ep.1 we see the Jedi have vast control, (political and military) over much of the Galaxy from fear, all through what they perceive as harmony. Then after Ep. 3 and thru Ep. 6 we see how the dark side uses the same force to control the same galaxy yet through fear and dominance. I cannot believe that the force would endow people with God like powers for them to use them for something as petty as controlling others. This is probably why we see times of equalizing.

Did Anakin bring balance? In my opinion yes, twice. Ep. 3 and Ep. 6. There will always be force sensitive people but I feel the Force leads them to where the Force needs them to keep it balanced even if that means at times tipping the scales, drastically. When I hear the term "bring balance to the Force". I think of life as a whole. There must be balance in life. I don't believe it's meant to just bring balance to a few light saber wielding individuals but to all life in the galaxy, even at the expense of a few billion lives.

Answer (score 2):

He spent half his life as a good guy, and half his life as a bad guy. The Jedi ruled, then the Sith ruled. Anakin lived the perfect yin/yang balance in terms of his own life. Never before had the galaxy seen such an extreme monarchy. The Jedi ruled more discretely, attempting to please the entire population by all their means. The Sith ruled with brute force and pure evil, solely for their own gain.

Anakin was a slave. He was the chosen one and had the highest midi-chlorian count ever. When Qui-Gon found him and freed him, he was given a chance to make everything right. He spent all his early years seeing the worst of the world. The Jedi gave him everything, food, clothes, a mentor and a job. He turned his back on everything the Jedi ever did for him for a greater power.

When the prophecy stated he would be the most powerful Jedi ever, they thought it meant through the force he would be powerful-which he was (until obi-wan had his way). The truth was his pure need to be with Padmé and his love for her was what made him more powerful than any Jedi. His emotions equaled his raw power. He had something that no other Jedi ever had, children. So for the first half of his life, he was fully set in abilities as the chosen one, however the Jedi were reluctant to train him strong enough to sense the dark side in time. They held him back so much (look at his potential and time span of being a Jedi and what he learned vs what Luke learned in the time span). The war Palpatine created distracted them from making Anakin the ultimate chosen one which was the force's original plan. But when the force sensed what Palpatine was planning to do, and knew the Jedi would fail, they implemented Padmé into Anakin's mind. The force knew if he had children he would be redeemed!

It was all the will of the force what happened. But it happened all too well. The Sith always worked by rule of two. One master, one apprentice who would surpass and kill his master, and so on. When obi wan stunted Anakin's potential, he blocked the Sith from ever continuing up the chain. If Vader would never surpass the emperor, he would never become a Sith lord and take an apprentice. Of course, Palpatine wanted this because he didn’t want to die, however he didn’t realize it made the Sith weak and extremely vulnerable. Little did he know, Anakin would kill him eventually not because he surpassed him, but because he loves his son and hates what Palpatine did to him. So in the end, Anakin's almighty powers served him no purpose in fulfilling the prophecy (which is what the Jedi originally believed would happen). His powers was their distraction, and vaders mechanical weakness was Palpatine's distraction. Both the Sith and the Jedi had to be in hiding to destroy each other, however the power of love proved greater than any power a Jedi or Sith could wield in their lifetime, and that is the moral of the story. Balance is love.

Comment: A lot of this sounds like speculation on your part...

Answer (score 2):

Leave a good mystery for everyone to solve.
The Sith had remained hidden for a thousand years, secretly waiting to take their vengeance. It was none other than Darth Sidious who decided when that perfect moment should be.  If Darth Sidious had waited any longer to make their existence known, then what would have happened? The Jedi would have no need to destroy the Sith; and thus, would have no need for a cosmic savior.  Though the following is not canon, I can agree with this:

> Brazen and shameless, and at their own mortal peril, they had waged
> etheric war, anticipating that their own midi-chlorians, the Force’s
> proxy army, might marshal to boil their blood or stop the beating of
> their hearts. Risen out of themselves, discorporate and as a single
> entity, they had brought the power of their will to bear, asserting
> their sovereignty over the Force.
>
> <sub>*[Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel))*</sub>

The Sith had changed the Force itself, to make the Jedi weaker.
If that were the case, then it’s reasonable to assume that the death of the Emperor would bring balance to the Force since he would no longer be around to corrupt it.  We can find another example of the Sith hi-jacking the Force in ROTS when Senator Palpatine tells Anakin about the Sith Legend of  Darth Plagueis “The Wise.”    It is my belief that Darth Sidious merely rode the coat-tails of his former master.  I believe Darth Plagueis was the closest thing to a father that Anakin Skywalker would ever have in the broadest sense; and Plagueis was more like a mad scientist, commanding the Force to create a super-conductive Force-wielding soldier to destroy the Jedi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Jacen Solo was actually the chosen one. The balance of the force is neither about numbers, nor peace. Peace is a Jedi construct. Balance refers to the USE of the force- for either light or darkness. If not for Luke, the Sith would have continued to exert dark side dominance. But the force is both light and dark- Ying and Yang. There must be both. So Luke extinguishes the Sith, finally. But now this is the least balanced the force has ever been. But Jacen Solo turns to the dark side, reving the Sith order, and restoring balance. The chosen one was always meant to be a Sith, and the Sith knew this. It's why Sidious hid the exact wording of the prophecy. Think about it... The Sith were almost wiped out in the Old Republic (The Jedi thought they WERE) so what exactly did the Jedi under Windu think the chosen one would do? The prophecy never said the Chosen One would squash the dark side... It said he would bring balance to ALL aspects of the force. Anakin Skywalker went too far, extinguishing the dominance of the light side ( The power of the dark side is great, so Vader and Sidious were stronger than Yoda and Obi-Wan. Luke went too far to defeat the Sith, by turning Vader and extinguishing the Sith dominance.  And with the Jedi council always too powerful (especially under Luke), that meant the chosen one would need to be a Sith who rose up against the Jedi, to temper their non-tollerance and power. Jacen Solo did this as a Sith Lord. He understood the balance and duality of the Force. He was crucial in driving the Vong from galactic space. He was Vader's grandson, son of Han and Leia, a twin like Luke and Leia, and nephew of Luke. He was the relative of very famous and important people, ie. stars. Or, as the prophecy says, "the son of suns".  Qui-Gon knew all this too, but believed Anakin would be the one. Qui-Gon's former master (Dooku) became Darth Tyranus, as he saw the truth. Obviously he taught this view to Qui-Gon, which is why Qui-Gon directly defied the council to train Anakin. Note all the negative comments Qui-Gon says about the council.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my previous post, supporting that The Jedi were clearly perpetrating an imbalance in the Force...
Obi-Wan denounces Anakin's love for Padme, because Jedi do not allow marriage or sex- yet Qui-Gon says "His father must have been a powerful Jedi.", implying (as we know) that Force-using is hereditary. So either most Jedi are perverted hypocrites who go around impregnating people, or they bend the truth to suit their own goals. Obi-Wan clearly shows rage as he fights then kills Darth Maul. He even tells Anakin "Only the Sith deal in absolutes", which is itself an absolute. Then he has the gaul to look disappointed when Anakin kills Dooku.  And Mace Windu is no better when he murders Jango Fett (in FRONT of his kid no less). And all so they can lead a bigoted war to keep lawful planets from declaring their own independance. Obi-Wan then kidnaps his former padawan's son, leaves him on the backwater hell-hole where Anakin was himself a slave (and where Anakin's mom was murdered), allows Owen and Maru to be inevitably murdered (even though he swore to look over the homestead), and then trains Anakin's only son to commit patricide through lies and deception- telling Luke that Vader killed his dad. Obi-wan even lets Vader kill him to intentionally enrage Luke. When Luke needs to go rescue his innocent friends from certain death in cloud city, Yoda tries to talk him out of it- greedily wanting Luke to do HIS bidding by training harder to kill Anakin. Do these sound like the actions of "the enlightened defenders of galactic peace"? And what did Palpatine do? He was greedy and seized power... and then saved Anakin's life and raised Vader like his own son, even making him a Lord in the Empire. So the Jedi, despite their outward appearance, are actually deeply flawed and hypocritical.

Comment: Jedi do allow sex. They only forbid emotional attachments like marriage. See: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/are-jedi-required-to-abstain-from-all-sexual-relations-or-only-from-the-ones-in

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a very simple issue. Jedi and Sith were trained in their respective arts. They either fell or changed sides. Anakin was birthed by the Force which knew no dark or light side. Anakin had both sides in him. Notice when he slew the younglings the Dark Side manifested itself in his eyes. But only a short time later when approached by Padme his eyes had changed back. Anakin could be both dark and light. But being imprisoned in his life support system as Vader, he swayed to the dark side. Luke also used the Dark Side to defeat Vader until he switched back.

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought that Anakin's role was to empower the Dark Side. Think about it, at the time, the the Jedi Order was going strong, and while there are still Siths in the universe, the total respective power were obviously overly tilted towards the Jedi's. In other words, it's imbalance in favour of the Light. In that sense, Anakin's role which is to "bring balance to the Force", involves making sure that the Light Side and the Dark Side of the Force are equal in number. As we can see with the result, the total number of Jedi and Sith were cut down to two vs two, not 21041024901249 vs 2.

Naturally, the above is something that George Lucas couldn't publicly announce, with people's perception of the movie all about being good and right and loving. He simply can't bring himself to ruin their fantasies. Same reason why he can't announce that Jar Jar Bink is a Sith Lord.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that Sideous & Plagius did something with months of meditation to cause "the dark side to cloud everything".  I think Anakin was created to counter that, possibly by killing the Sith that did that, or by filling the future with Skywalkers - super powerful predominately light side force users.

I think it's too bad Anakin wasn't found by one of the other Jedi or force user groups that don't deny attachments and wouldn't have had issues with his age, wouldn't have thought the way to deal with his fear for his mother was to tell him to forget her.

The Coruscanti Jedi were idiots.

Answer (score 0):

What most people dont realize is anakins father was the force. Therefore, the force as his father guided his actions. 
Most of the things Anakin did was pure will of the force, yet we all dont realize it. 
He was meant to be only a jedi, and this is where the story gets interesting.
Since Anakins father was the force, he never had a physical father to feel, touch , or relate to. He also only knew his mother until he was 9, only so that 10 years later he could watch her die.
Anakin desperately craved a FATHER. 
Palpatine took advantage of Anakin by pretending to be the father figure he always wanted, the master he always craved, and the savior of his family. That is why it is called "the tragedy of Darth Vader".
However, it is unclear if Palpatine knew they could actually receive the power, but we do know Anakin was convinced of his own potential and in the ways and views on the force of Palpatine. The Dogma of the Jedi reminded him too much of his slavery, when in fact his slavery made it easier for him to be a jedi.
It is very complicated because the jedi are emotionless but anakin was 9 and full of emotion. The jedis biggest mistake was when they met anakin they gave away all of their abilities to him, so the first thing he learned to HIDE was his EMOTIONS from the JEDI. At the same time, unknowingly spilling the beans to palpatine that the jedi have found "the chosen one" a 9 year old boy. Anakins whole life he never had a choice, slavery or jedi, then jedi or nobody. Palpatine spent almost 20 years pretending to be the father figure he always craved, wanted... The mentor he "needed" with EMOTIONAL support. 
Sith use EMOTION AS THEIR POWER! So if Anakin learned to hide his emotions young from the jedi council, surely he learned how to hide everything from the sand people slaughter, to marrying and impregnating Padme. The real tragedy is he never felt the need to hide anything from palpatine! So everything the jedi should have protected anakin from, pushed him right towards it.
The real answer is the jedi HAD to be almost wiped out completely for yoda to realize he made an army of laser deflecting slaves and soldiers. Underlings. He never let anyone past him out of fear of the dark side. "Fear is a path to the dark side" but the truth is "fear feeds the dark side ". 
Once the jedi were wiped out and only after did they realize how truly cruel palpatine was and is, and that they had to change their ways.
Luke was very old when he started his training and in the middle of adulthood emotional instability, but still a very calm and honorable young man. Everything Anakin was not at his age. He learned to love hate regret every emotion under the stars, and when he was being trained yoda warned luke of his emotions, but didnt tell him he couldnt go further because of his fear. Yoda can defend himself against any dark side maniac if he can evenly match palpatine, and he knows this ONLY AFTER THE PURGE. The real reason they left luke to grow so old is so that he would be more human like shmi and padme than jedi like either them or obi wan. Also it would have created a verge in the force , so they waited for signs from the force and honed the rest of their talents for years. 
Their goal became eliminating the sith: again the wrong thing to do. Anakins job is to father the balance and no one elses, not mace windus when he attempts to assassinate palpatine, nor yoda when he attempts to end sidious at the end of episode 3. Thats why they failed. Not only not allowing anakin past them or anyone else, Palpatine became as powerful as yoda in 1/10th the time using the sith way, and the real tragedy is if yoda trained anakin like luke since day 1 anakin would have brought balance much sooner. Anakin got robbed by everyone, the jedi by fear of what is to come and the sith by wanting to rule the galaxy unopposed. 
Balance was really brought down to a phoenix rising from the ashes. Essentially wiping out all sides of the force clean and a phoenix (Luke) arises from the ashes (Good side). Destroying the sith was more complicated than igniting a light saber so to speak and trying your best. Yoda and obi wan never learned this, but maybe qui-gon did.
But the sith cannot be destroyed because of the sith way. This is very complicated to understand, because the master never kills the apprentice, ever. Anakin becoming vader created palpatines perfect galaxy governing paradox. They spent many years ruling the galaxy as master and apprentice. But at this point, this is not the father-son relationship anakin wanted nor did anything go his way. His anger fuels every decision. Anger from
Losing everything: padme,the jedi, his friends, his full potential... All gone
But there was something left inside Anakin. The ability to love, and the craving for a father. How did Anakin fully defeat the sith?
What was it Luke was shouting for when Palpatine was zapping him? FATHER. Something Anakin never had. Something Vader is not, and something ANAKIN IS. FATHER! So Anakin became the first ever sith in history to destroy his master NOT to become the NEXT SITH MASTER, fully destroying the future of sith legacy.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any sources to back this up?  Thanks!

Comment: Please split this wall of text into paragraphs for your readers. And proper capitalization and punctuation would help, too.

Comment: Holy wall of text Batman.  This might be useful with some formatting.  Paragraphs please.

Answer (score 0):

Anakin brought balance by first stopping the light by becoming Vader when the light was too powerful. Then, he stopped the dark when it was too powerful. He also ended the sith, who were causing unbalance.

Comment: Technically he didn't end the Sith but aside that he crippled both the Sith and the Jedi. If you eliminate both opposing forces, nature should resume a balance.

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert but I love Star Wars I am impressed with everyone's theory on weather the prophecy is for filled. What if in different perspective and with a certain view Anakin did bring balance by fathering twins a boy and girl, "female" and "male" energy of the force? Just a thought I had I am sorry if it doesn't make sense. But I think in more then one way he brought balance to the force, he was good and evil he was also nieve thinking he could use the darkness to save Padame. But he distroys the Sith an altamenly distroying himself but he did it by the love of son, Luke saved him and he saved Luke this bringing balance by 'life and death' his sacrifice including the death of the sith and preserving His sons life so the Jedi and light of force can carry on.

Comment: An interesting theory, but please back up theories presented in answers with evidence rather than just speculation. Please take a look at the [help] to get acquainted with the site. Welcome to SFF.SE!