# How does the Prophecy of the Chosen One relate to the EU?

Tags: star-wars

George Lucas gave the definitive interpretation of the meaning of the prophecy of the Chosen One and the phrase "balance to the Force" on the Revenge of the Sith commentary track:

> "[...] Which brings us up to the films 4, 5, and 6, in which Anakin's offspring redeem him and allow him to fulfill the prophecy where he brings balance to the Force by *doing away with the Sith and getting rid of evil in the universe...*"

How does this fit in with the Star Wars Expanded Universe that takes place after the defeat of Palpatine? The EU depicts plenty of evil people, users of the Dark Side, and even some Sith. Has anyone tried to reconcile Lucas' statement with that material?

My understanding is that EU has a complicated system of canonicity, where the films trumps everything, but everything else has varying degrees of canonicity. So is pretty much everything post-RotJ non-canonical?

Comment: I guess this question will be even more relevant with the new upcoming trilogy - while this is purely speculation, it seems pretty unlikely that our heroes (whoever they may be) won't be facing any 'evil' during the movies. Luke and Leia rebuilding the Jedi and the Republic is interesting, but hardly blockbuster material...

Comment: Yes and no. Previous to the recent announcement by Disney, the EU books were "C Canon". This meant that anything in the books that was not directly contradicted by any official movies, tv shows or specials was considered "canon", with the caveat that new official material could come out and wipe out the EU stories (Boba Fett was victim to this). With the new announcement by Disney, all of the EU material such as books, games, etc is definitively split into a separate canon from the movies and tv shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recent purchase of the Star Wars franchise by Disney, the old canon has questionable bearing. Previously, the [canon structure](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon#Canon_in_the_Holocron_continuity_database) had the films (G-canon) above the EU novels (C-canon). The key point to note is that the EU was *still considered canonical*, but Lucas was `not beholden to it` (i.e. he could invalidate it with new films or TV shows if he so desired).

Under Disney, the old EU works are no longer considered canon, being rebranded "Legends", but new works (those starting with *A New Dawn*) will be on an equal footing with the films. Post-ROTJ works are explicitly non canon for now, though they may choose to incorporate elements of them in new works. It is rumored that older (pre-Ep III) works will be incorporated into the new canon, as Disney's focus is primarily on the post-ROTJ timeline, but this is as of now unconfirmed.

So in answer to your last question: **Yes, as of now, all post-ROTJ EU works are non-canonical**.

With regards to your first question, no, I have never seen any attempt at reconciliation towards that in the EU. One of the central themes of Star Wars has been the struggle between good and evil, and the balance of the two, which in EU works obviously continued long after the fall of the Empire. Lucas has on several occasions made statements and then contradicted himself, so such a broad statement must be taken with a grain of salt. Lucas' own view of canonicity was more restrictive than the guidelines set forward by his company, so you have to choose how much to follow one set of guidelines or another.

In regards to relating the Chosen One to balancing the force in the EU, see either of the top two answers  (*disclaimer: one of them is mine*) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/how-was-the-chosen-one-meant-to-bring-balance-to-the-force?answertab=votes#tab-top), and note that the accepted answer does reference that same quote, though not really in the way you were asking.