# Has Yoda ever killed a Sith Lord or Dark Jedi Master and, if so, who?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

I heard Yoda killed a Sith but I know Yoda is not about killing. I've researched it, but can't find any actual proof. Has Yoda ever killed a Sith Lord or Dark Jedi Master and, if so, who?

Comment: I am 99% sure he hasnt. The only time i can think of he might have is after he fled to Dagobah. Someone might have tracked him there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yoda never killed a Sith Lord, either in canon or in [Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends). This is mainly due to the fact that there are so [few Sith Lords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Lord/Canon) due to the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two/Canon). The following is the complete canon list of known Sith Lords alive during Yoda's lifetime:

1. Darth Plagueis (murdered by his apprentice, Darth Sidious)
2. Darth Maul (thought to be killed by Obi-Wan Kenobi, ultimate fate unknown)
3. Darth Tyranus (murdered by Anakin Skywalker)
4. Darth Sidious (killed by Anakin Skywalker)
5. Darth Vader (fatally wounded by Darth Sidious' Force Lightning)

There are of course Sith Lords who came before these and were alive during Yoda's long (900 year) life, but Yoda did not even know of their existence because [the Jedi thought the Sith were extinct until the reign of Darth Plagueis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102823/31936). Yoda did *try* to kill Tyranus (Count Dooku) and Sidious (Palpatine), but failed. (Oh, the irony.)

An [archived character profile of Yoda on starwars.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20110911123202/http://www.starwars.com/databank/character/yoda/index.html) mentions that he killed a Bpfasshi Dark Jedi on Dagobah. [Wookieepedia's article on the Bpfasshi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bpfasshi) confirms this. However, this incident is in Legends and therefore non-canon. I cannot find any other example of Yoda killing a Dark Jedi, either in canon or in Legends.

In summary: **Yoda never killed a Sith Lord either in canon or Legends, he never killed a Dark Jedi in canon, and he only killed one Dark Jedi in Legends.**

That said, it's not true that "Yoda is not about killing". He has killed other people, including clones:

[image]

Comment: Does killing a clone count as long as there are still some clones left?

Comment: They aren't a hive mind. That instance had some, small, degree of individuality which Yoda snuffed out.

Comment: It always seemed to me that Yoda was not trying very hard to kill Darth Tyranus.  It seemed more like he was trying to make a point about the light side (while not being defeated)--his tactics during the battle were very light-sidey, but not really designed for maximum effectiveness.  For example, rocks thrown aside instead of back towards Tyranus (when Yoda clearly had superior control); allowing Tyranus to choose the nature of the engagement (when he has a huge height/reach advantage in lightsaber combat), etc..

Comment: @RexKerr I think Yoda was attempting to show Tyranus that the light side was as powerful as the dark in order to perhaps turn him back to the light. But if Tyranus hadn't escaped so soon I think Yoda would have had to more actively go for the kill.

Comment: @Null - Perhaps.  Anyway, my point is that I'm not entirely sure it's fair to say that Yoda did _try_ to kill Tyranus.  It didn't look to me like that was his objective.

Comment: Re: Bpfasshi canonicity: Sadly, this is even worse than that. Although the "Bpfasshi Dark Jedi" was one of my favorite EU storylines, it became non-canon (N canon, and not C-canon) level even before Disney/Legends canon reshuffle, as a result of deliberate canon decisions by George Lucas surrounding the fan-slapping merchandizing moneymaking scheme (aka the Prequel films)

Comment: @DVK No need to be so vague about it; tell us how you really feel. ;-)

Comment: @Null: Yoda should have just done this: https://youtu.be/0cxjlN9e9-c?t=3m52s

Comment: Vader didn't die from force lightning, he died because darth sidious' power was keeping him alive after what oBiwan did to him in revenge of the sith. I thought it was made overtly obvious by the fact he had plenty of strength to throw the emporer then immediately fell and struggled to breathe when he died... like his lungs had been scorched by breathing lava fumes or something.

Comment: I was wondering for how long the Jedi had thought the Sith were extinct. The link indicates it was since about 100 years before Yoda's birth. Seems like good information to add to this answer, rather than just link. (+1)

Comment: @Matt Do you have a source to back that up? Seemed to me that Vader was just acting with the last ounce of strength he could muster at the sight of his son being tortured by the Emperor. There are many documented cases in reality of parents performing practically superhuman feats in order to save their child. When adrenaline *really* kicks in, you can do some crazy stuff. Vader was half cyborg/robot after his ill-fated fight with Obi-Wan; it probably wasn't difficult physically for him to lift a ~90-year-old, ~100-pound-looking man and toss him into a hole.

Answer (score 1):

In the Thrawn Trilogy, it's mentioned that Yoda killed a Bpfasshi Dark Jedi
on Dagobah. This death created the dark side cave.

Somehow, Mon Mothma learned the story, and told Han and Leia. The Falcon went 
to see the Bpfasshi, to bring them into the New Republic, and were attacked by the
Noghri.