# When was the 1st time in the Star Wars movies that a character has confirmed Anakin over Luke as the chosen one?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

**To address comments:**

1

TheLethalCarrot♦: I might be missing something to what you're asking but isn't TPM full of Qui-Gon Jinn talking about Anakin being the Chosen One.

Me: I thought Qui-Gon thought but wasn't sure Anakin was the chosen one? Why else wouldn't those answers quote Qui-Gon ?

2

Valorum: Unfortunately asking a narrower question is still a duplicate. If you want more detail about x, create a bounty on the dupe that says "I'll offer a bounty for information about X"

Me: Says who? Is that specific to SFF se? Or in general? I've never heard this rule even in other sites like maths se, stats se, physics se, it's common to create new questions asking for different proofs.

---

Previous question [Who was "The Chosen One": Luke or Anakin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4724/who-was-the-chosen-one-luke-or-anakin) identifies Anakin as chosen one but uses either out-of-universe info or in-universe info but not in the movies.

**Here's what I remember**:

1. In SW1-6, no **character** explicitly stated which between Luke or Anakin is the chosen one. Afaiu, Qui-Gon thought but wasn't sure Anakin was the chosen one.
2. In SW7-8, still nothing from a **character**.
3. In SW9, **Anakin** whispers to Rey 'Bring back the balance, Rey, as I did.'
4. (3) is confirmation that the chosen one is Anakin instead of Luke.

**Question:**  Are those right?

Comment: @JoeW LOL I know it is Anakin, but I wanna know how specifically from the movies only we know that. The answers there use out of the movies.

Comment: I still don't see the difference in those two questions.

Comment: Still seems like your answer can be gotten in the other question.

Comment: @JoeW I don't see a single mention of Rey there.

Comment: @JoeW I don't see in-universe answers there.

Comment: Adding extra provisos doesn't make this not a duplicate. If you don't like the answers on the other question, the done thing is to raise a bounty over there, not to just re-ask it

Comment: @Valorum Huh? I want to use a specific source. It's like I want a Catholic answer when the other answers given are Protestant on Bible Hermeneutics

Comment: I might be missing something to what you're asking but isn't TPM full of Qui-Gon Jinn talking about Anakin being the Chosen One.

Comment: @BCLC - Unfortunately asking a *narrower* question is still a duplicate. If you want more detail about x, create a bounty on the dupe that says "***I'll offer a bounty for information about X***"

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I thought Qui-Gon thought but wasn't sure Anakin was the chosen one? Why else wouldn't those answers quote Qui-Gon ?

Comment: @Valorum Says who? Is that specific to SFF se? Or in general? I've never heard this rule even in other sites like maths se, stats se, physics se, it's common to create new questions asking for different proofs.

Comment: @BCLC  - Consider "*What are these objects?*" vs. "*What is this object?*".

Comment: @Valorum What are you talking about? I'm asking more like 'How do you prove Fermat's last theorem without the Taniyama–Weil-Shimura conjecture?'

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If Qui-Gon wasn't sure about Anakin, then are you gonna reopen this?

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes the easy answer is the definitive answer, remember that the prequels, as their name states, were made after the original Trilogy, Anakin killing Sidious was something that has already happened before the idea of "The Chosen One" was even developed, in other words, there was no mention of "The Chosen One" in the OT and we already knew the outcome.

Now recap what the prequels told us, they start with an immaculate conceived child (a direct reference to Jesus Christ) with a higher force affinity than Master Yoda and everything we know about him is that he "Might be the child of the prophecy" while the prophecy states:

"A Chosen One shall come, born of no father, and through him will ultimate balance in the Force be restored."

Sounds too obvious, the plan was never to dispute whether it was Luke or Anakin, those were mere fan speculations and theories because "hey, Anakin failed and destroyed the Jedi Order", but the OT was already a story of redemption, Anakin failing was something that must have happened, George's main idea was simply "Anakin is the Chosen One".

Comment: Just because the prequels came later doesn't mean that the story from them wasn't considered when making the ones that get released first.

Comment: Thanks. 'Anakin failing was something that must have happened, George's main idea was simply "Anakin is the Chosen One".'  --> Hmmm...but this is an interpretation from out-of-universe... I'll edit to clarify that I mean in-universe

Comment: @JoeW what I mean with "came later" is that we already knew what the outcome was, if they'd been chronological then I would understand speculation just before Episode VI came out about who would be The Chosen One, the one who'd bring balance by killing Sidious, but that wasn't the case, we already knew it was Anakin the one who did it, so the prequels weren't made with the idea of disputing whether it was Luke or Anakin, they were made with the idea of Anakin being TCO.

Comment: I don't see how what we know is going to happen really matters as it is the writer who choses who is the "chosen one" and not the viewers.

Comment: @JoeW  Yeah, and that's what I'm saying, George has already stated in the past that Anakin is TCO and the Jedi Order merely misinterpreted the prophecy.

Comment: @BCLC Well, I mean, if you want an in universe answer you have The Clone Wars Episodes where Anakin literally tames both The Bright Side and The Dark Side of the force after being told just TCO could do it, if you are merely asking about movies I already said why there's "No clarification"; because in e IV-VI there's no mention of it since it was not a concept back then, in e I-III there's just mentions of Anakin being TCO as it was the original idea, Luke being TCO was a fan theory.

Comment: 'The Clone Wars Episodes ' --> I said movies only......